# JDBC Teradata exception: Two different data types are being set for parameter

Tags: java, jdbc, groovy, teradata

При вставке через JDBC batch двух строк с одним столбцом, первая строка null, вторая 12 - получаю исключение Two different data types are being set for parameter 1, понимаю, что драйвер не может в один столбец внести и тип null и INTEGER, может кто обходил это недоразумение?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, как-то так. 
ps.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);

Comment: Спасибо, натолкнули на нужную мысль.

Answer (score 0):

sqlTo.withBatch(connections.batchSize, queryTo) { ps ->    sqlFrom.query(queryFrom) { resultSet ->

```
    //получаем данные о столбцах
    def rsmt = resultSet.getMetaData()     
    def colCount = rsmt.getColumnCount()
    def mapColumn = [:]
    1.upto(colCount){
        def columnName = rsmt.getColumnTypeName(it)
        def nameColumn = listFieldFrom[it - 1]
        println nameColumn

        mapColumn[nameColumn] = columnName
        println columnName
    }
    println mapColumn    

    получаем данные из столбцов
    while (resultSet.next()) {

        def listFromResult = []  

        listFieldFrom.each{
            def type = mapColumn[it]
            def data = resultSet.getObject(it)
            listFromResult << Sql."$type"(data)
        }      

        if (counter % connections.batchSize == 0) println "--> set batch: ${counter}"
        ps.addBatch(listFromResult)
        counter++
    }
}
```

}